# Rails 3.0 :remote => true with ie9 will double submit form when I click on submit button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-9, ujs

I have a Rails 3.0 app which is using a normal :remote => true option for a form_for.  It works correctly in all browsers except IE9.  Even IE8 works ok.  But in IE9, I can see by using the F12 developer tool that it is issuing 2 requests to the server when I click the submit button.

Here's the form_for:

> <%= form_for @project, :project, :url => create_project_url, :remote => true do |f| %>

Here's the submit button:

> <%= submit_tag 'Create' %>

Looking at the F12 information it shows 1 request initiated by "JS Library XMLHttpRequest" and one initiated by "click".

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent this?

Comment: try to upgrade rails-ujs and jquery, maybe this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.  Upgrading my prototype.js and rails.js files to the latest did the trick.  Upgrading the prototype.js file was the most important, but I did the rails.js one just to make sure.

Here's a link to the latest prototype.js download:
http://www.prototypejs.org/download